# Grouping data in a graph

Tags: if-statement, graph, dax, multiple-conditions, group

In Power BI , there are the following columns in the "BI" table:

```
Column B: Whether "OTP" is Validated or not (1 = Validated and 0= Not validated)  
Column C: OTP number (there are several OTPs per customer)  
Column D: Customer name (There are several instances of the same customer name)  
Column E: BU location  
Column F: Consultant's name  
Column G: Month of issue (Example: 1 = January, 2 = February, etc.)  
Column H: The current month (Example: 12 = December)
```

Next, I'd like to create another table with every customer who meets the following conditions:

- If all the OTPs of a customer older than 3 months are in state 1, then the customer is "validated".
- If a customer's OTPs are in states 2 and 3 over 3 months, but there are no OTPs in state 4 over 3 months, then the customer is "overdue".
- If all a customer's OTPs are in state 4, then the customer is "unused".

Thanks for your help.

I tried to create several tables via DAX but never succeeded.

Comment: Is there a standard date column on this table, or just Month of issue? What about previous or future years? Please update your question to include your table with a few sample or mock rows (in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/))